# facing error while nstalling mysql in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-error-1064

im trying to install mysql-community-server_5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb.
before that i have ran the commands
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

after that im facing the below error. cn anyone provide me the solution.

```
testuser@mon-mod:/usr/mysql$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-community-server_5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 63795 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-server_5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb ...
.
Unpacking mysql-community-server (5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04) over (5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-server:
 mysql-community-server depends on mysql-common (= 5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04); however:
  Package mysql-common is not installed.
 mysql-community-server depends on mysql-client (= 5.7.13-1ubuntu16.04); however:
  Package mysql-client is not installed.
 mysql-community-server depends on libmecab2 (>= 0.996-1.2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libmecab2 is not installed.
 mysql-community-server depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1.
 mysql-community-server depends on init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~); however:
  Version of init-system-helpers on system is 1.14.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
testuser@mon-mod:/usr/mysql$
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `apt-get` package manager in the Ubuntu  to install MySQL server. It will take care of the dependencies. In Ubuntu you can use

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

Comment: the server doesnt have internet connection. so can you provide inputs  how to install offline